# Как передать GET-параметры на JS

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

Django 1.6

У меня сейчас так, но это не работает.
Вызываю метод при нажатии на кнопку:

```
$scope.btn = function () {
    var From = $scope.From;
    window.open("{% url 'mysite' From="YPA!!!" %}", '_blank');
};
```

Далее в обработчике URL-ов `url(r'^bla/$', View.as_view(), name='mysite'),` происходит передача данных на обработчик:

```
class MyView(View):
http_method_names = ['get']
template_name = 'bla/mysite.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    # Данные GET-запроса получать из "request.GET.*"

    print request.GET.From
```

Но в результате `print` ничего не выводит. Как правильно передать через GET имя переменной со значением`From="YPA!!!"` в обработчик?

---

Попробовал так:

```
window.open("{% url 'mysite' %}" + "?From=YPA!!!", '_blank');
```

Но выводит ошибку:

```
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'From'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам необходимо либо подкорректировать route, либо указать get параметры явно.

1 способ: `url(r'^bla/(?P<From>[\-_\D\d]+)$', View.as_view(), name='mysite')`

2 способ: `window.open("{% url 'mysite' %}" + "?From=YPA!!!", '_blank');`

---

Еще неправильное обращение к полученным GET-переменным. Надо так:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print request.GET.get('From')
```

Comment: как выглядит полный url?

Comment: Спасибо. Уже справился с ошибкой.

Comment: @EmptyMan кул, было бы интересно узнать в чем была проблема :)

Comment: у меня был еще не правильный вывод GET-параметра.